# Read DSN name from config file to connect to SQL Server in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc

I'm trying to read DSN name form an input file, instead of hardcoding, and connecting to SQL Server using SQLDriverConnect. Getting an error "Data Source name not found and no default driver specified SQLSTATE IM002".

Here's the code

```
void connectToStaging (ConnectionConfig &cConfig)
{   
  std::string inConnString = cConfig.getValueOfKey<std::string>("DSN");
  rc = SQLDriverConnect (hConn, NULL, (SQLCHAR*) inConnString.c_str(), SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
if (!(rc==0 || rc==1))
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hConn);
}
```

Connection.config file:
DSN="DSN=DSNDEV;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

Comment: And what is the actual value of `inConnString`?

Comment: Also, don't use magic numbers when checking what `SQLDriverConnect` returns, use the predefined symbolic names.

Comment: I'm reading value of DSN key in config file to inConnString (DSN="DSN=DSNDEV;Trusted_Connection=yes;"). Sure, I'll use SQL_SUCCESS and SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO from now on.

Comment: But what is the *actual* value of the string? Are you 100% sure that `cConfig.getValueOfKey<std::string>("DSN")` returns the correct value?

Comment: If the actual value of `inConnString` is `DSN=DSNDEV;Trusted_Connection=yes;' and you're still getting the error, then it's likely a mismatch of bitness, i.e. you're using a 64-bit app to load a 32-bit DSN or vice versa, especially if the DSN loads correctly from a different application.